# JQuery Load function returns 405 Method not Allowed

Tags: jquery, python, google-app-engine, polymer

I am dealing with a web app based on Google App Engine (Python).
I am trying to update a div from a Polymer (HTML) element. The Div I need to update is actually the element's container. 
To this end, from the element's javascript snippet I am trying to get the div object through Jquery and invoking its load method like

```
 $('#myContainerId').load('/myQueryUrl?id=123123123');
```

The problem is that I get 405 Method Not Allowed

**UPDATE**

the url is bound to a Python webapp.RequestHandler through the app's yaml file which implements the get method, makes a query to the ndb and render a Jinja2 template.

**UPDATE 2**

The error in the consol log, when expanded, says:

```
k.cors.a.crossDomain.send 
n.extend.ajax 
n.fn.load 
(anonymous function) 
j 
k.fireWith 
x 
(anonymous function)
```

It says there is a cross domain although the domains are actually the same

Comment: Please place you server code, that process request `/myQueryUrl`

Comment: the url is bound to a Python webapp.RequestHandler through the app's yaml file which implements the get method, makes a query to the ndb and render a Jinja2 template.

Comment: Did you mean /myQueryUrl?id=123123123 ?

Comment: please check my further update...

Comment: @lowcoupling Did you notice the `?` instead of `&` in the url that @r.pankevicius mentions? When using an `&` as the first character after a url, the browser interprets `id=XXX` as part of the url

Comment: yes I fixed that but the issue remains. May it be because I am invoking load from a polymer-element?

Comment: Can you include some code that shows how you have defined your `/myQueryUrl` route as well as the `webapp2.RequestHandler` class that is handling the request -- specifically the `get` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use $.ajax() instead of $.load() to control the request/response explicitly. This may do the trick (*you may need to adjust the params*):

```
$('#myContainerId').ajax({
  crossDomain: FALSE,
  type: "POST", // || GET || PUT || DELETE
  url: '/myQueryUrl?id=123123123'
});
```

Comment: now it says "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function".go

Comment: make sure that you include the jquery.js file

Comment: jQuery needs to be loaded before you call your script.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try using a more explicit method pertaining to using .POST data. As long as you have more recent version of JQuery that you are running. The [.POST](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) method [`$.post("fileHandler.php", {"..."), function(data) {...});`] might be more suited to this situation.

**End Result:**

```
$.post("myHandler.php", {urlToReceive: jsUrlStoredVariable}, function(data) {
    //What to do when your data is returned...
});
```

However, as far as your current problem is remaining...

Since no error reports, JSFiddles or code samples have really been provided

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('#myContainerId').load('myQueryUrl?id=123123123');
```

Comment: could you elaborate on this?